# Can't save Facebook accessToken in SDK 3.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-access-token

I've been using the old Facebook SDK and saved the `accessToken` and `expirationDate` inside the `NSUserDefaults`. But now in the new `Facebook SDK 3.2` there is a new class called `FBAccessTokenData` and I can take the accessToken from there by using:

```
[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken
[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.expirationDate
```

My problem is when I restart my app and click on Facebook button again, it goes to Facebook to ask for a new token although I used the app 3 minutes before, login into Facebook and got new token. So the token hasn't been saved.

I'm trying to save the new `accessToken` into `[FBSession activeSession]` but `accessToken` and `expirationDate` are **readonly** properties.

I've been reading the Facebook SDK documentation for few times now, searched stackOverflow and the web and still didn't got any clue how to do that.

This is my code:

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
        {
            // This is how i'm trying to save the token, like the old Facebook SDK.
            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [defaults setObject:[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
            [defaults setObject:[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.expirationDate forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
            [defaults synchronize];

            NSLog(@"FB: Session is open!");
        }
            break;

        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
        {
            NSLog(@"FB: Session is closed or login failed");

            [self closeSession];
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FBSessionStateChangedNotification
                                                        object:session];

    if (error)
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:error.localizedDescription
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}


- (void)openSession
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
    {
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
    }];
}

- (void)closeSession
{
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found the answer after searching more, If someone has problem with the new `Facebook SDK 3.2` `accessToken`, look at this [**link**](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/token-caching-ios-sdk/). and you'll find what you are looking for.

Basically you create a class that handles the token saving and loading. Than you save it into local plist file - pretty easy and simple.

Enjoy! :)